# Backup Bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, backup

I am currently using Ubuntu directly from the USB drive because I have problems with my hard drive. I would like to know how to backup my bootable USB drive after each use so that I can save files and programs without uploading them to a cloud service.

In other words, is there a way that I can save programs and/or files using the bootable USB if my hard drive is not usable?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want is called **Persistence**.

## If you want to make a new USB, with persistence:

Many Linux USB creators offer an option to enable Persistence.

In Ubuntu's USB creator:

[image: Ubuntu's USB Creator - Persistence]

And Unetbootin (Windows tool to create Linux bootable USBs):

[image: Unetbootin]

## If you want to make your *existing* USB Persistent:

1. Create an empty file called `casper-rw` in the USB's root using the
   disk-writing tool `dd`.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/usb/casper-rw bs=2G count=1
   ```

   This will create 2 GB of storage for your files and programs. To increase it, modify the `2G` in the command to increase. (For example, to get 4 GB of storage, `2G` would be replaced with `4G`)

   Replace `/path/to/usb` with the path to your USB (usually  along the lines of `/media/USERNAME/USB_NAME`
2. Make a filesystem on that file:

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 /path/to/usb/casper-rw
   ```
3. Edit the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` file in your pen-drive's root. Look for the line starting with `linux`.
   Before the `--` at the end, add `persistent`;
   so that the line's ending looks like: `persistent --`.

Now whatever changes you make, they'll be saved.